# How can i SELECT datas from 2 tables basing my query on the nearest value of a record?

Tags: sql

I have to tables: element and features.
I would like to select the records with the nearest values to another record.

I select 2 ids: mainimageid and elementid, and other 3 data fields: bp, ep, and symbolid.
In the SELECT clause i put  the alias `DIFF, DIFFbp and DIFFep` that are absolute values of the difference of these datas.
in the `FROM clause` i put the 2 tables
and in the `WHERE: symbolid = 8`
last: i order the result by `DIFF, DIFFbp and DIFFep`

This is my SQL query:-

```
SELECT mainimageid,
       elementid,
       symbolid,
       features.bp,
       features.ep,
       ABS (features.elongation - 2.63) AS DIFF,
           ABS (features.bp - 1) AS DIFFbp,
               ABS (features.ep - 4) AS DIFFepFROM iesp_schema.element,
                   iesp_schema.features
WHERE symbolid = 8
  AND mainimageid <> 622
ORDER BY mainimageid,
         DIFF,
         DIFFbp,
         DIFFep
```

My result is a very long list of 6755 rows (i do not have all this record!)

I posted below partial results of my query.
I notice first that i have the data value fields different but with that same ids,that is not possible!

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are cross joining the tables, because you forgot the join clause:

```
WHERE element.some_id = features.some_id
```

That wouldn't have happened with up-to-date join syntax:

```
FROM iesp_schema.element
INNER JOIN iesp_schema.features ON element.some_id = features.some_id
```

Answer (score 3):

What are you doing is basically performing a cartesian product between the rows of the tables ie element and features.
If you suspect very high number of rows are being returned , it means you are missing the JOINING condition in your query. Joining condition is the common column between the two tables.

The recommended ANSI SQL way to do join is like below

```
SELECT <column_List>
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB
ON tableA.columnName = tableB.columnName
```

In your query , you forgot to give the joining condition but still the query was syntactically correct and gave you the incorrect large result.

In above format , if join condition as specified by `ON` clause is omitted , query throws error allowing to catch error beforehand.